# Analog to negating .filter()

Tags: java, filter, stream, negate

So I have a stream and I am trying to filter it. Every object inside that stream has one of 5 different statuses. Every item that has one specified status is gonna make that list. Then I'll use a `foreach` to change another attribute of those filtered objects.

The thing is: I have to do something with the objects that were filtered out of my list. So I need a way to get them too, but since there are like 5 different statuses I didn't want to put all of them inside another filter.

Is there a way of putting an `if`/`else` inside the filter or `foreach`? Is there a way to negate the filtering?

Cannot post code because it is proprietary.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `Collectors.groupingBy(YourObject::getStatus)`

Comment: If you want five different categories, use `groupingBy`.  If you want two categories, use `partitioningBy`.

Answer (score 0):

From the description of your problem I assume you are looking for the negation of `.filter()` method from Stream API. Assuming the method invocation looks as following:

```
stream.filter(booleanExpression)
```

to get the stream of elements filtered out from the invacation above use the following:

```
stream.filter(!booleanExpression)
```